# YAML properties from AWS ECS-CLI compose are not documented

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

All,

I'm trying to automate my AWS ECS cluster setup via scripting.
I found the AWS ecs-cli to create task definitions and it's corresponding documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-create.html

I am able to create task definition and log group with the following two docker-compose files

1)service-security-docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
    services:
      ps-security-service-test:
        image: ...-east-1.amazonaws.com/security:latest
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        logging:
          driver: awslogs
          options:
            awslogs-group: /ecs/20200208-security
            awslogs-region: us-east-1
            awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
```

2)service-security-ecs-params.yml

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  services:
    ps-security-service-test:
      mem_limit: 750MB
```

This configuration creates a task definition with the name "service".
I would like to change the name and have a look which other parameters can be set with the yaml configuration.

At this point I got blocked as I can't find which properties I can use to e.g. set the name of the task definition/service.

Does someone know where to find the yaml configuration documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ECS CLI docker-compose file is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-parameters.html) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#versioning).

The ECS params file is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-ecsparams.html).

Answer (score 1):

AWS did release [support for v3 of docker compose syntax](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-ecs-cli-supports-docker-compose-version-3/) so your first stop is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). Important to note, however, AWS is not aligned with the latest v3 release (3.7) so anything that doesn't yet work is probably noted in the [AWS Container Roadmap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/labels/ECS). You can also find specifics about Task Definition on [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) of the ECS docs.

So, in summary:

1. Start with v3 docker compose format
2. Specific to the task definition, try `family` which per the docs is "similar to a name for multiple versions of the task definition, specified with a revision number"
3. If that doesn't get you where you need to be, log an issue on GitHub linked above

Comment: where can I set the family property in the yaml files?

Answer (score 0):

With the answers posted above, I could find the answer.
First of all, these are indeed the pages where you can find information about all the possible parameters:

1. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#versioning
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-up.html
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-ecsparams.html

Then I still had the issue that I couldn't configure the family property of the task definition. When I looked at the example of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-up.html I saw that the yaml files where not defining the family name that was mentioned in the displayed console log. Like that I found out that the "family" property is set by the "--project-name" parameter of the cli command.